# How to mount zfs pools created on a different disk

Tags: linux, zfs

I Upgraded my kernel and the driver letter changed so I lost my zfs disks (this is a test system).

So I wanted to know how to recover them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zmt       -      -      -      -      -  FAULTED  -
zmt1      -      -      -      -      -  FAULTED  -
zmt0      -      -      -      -      -  FAULTED  -
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool import zmt0
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zmt       -      -      -      -      -  FAULTED  -
zmt0   476G   443G  33.3G    93%  1.15x  ONLINE  -
zmt1      -      -      -      -      -  FAULTED  -

root@kkron-desktop:/# ls /zmt0
cache  kkron  PortableApps

root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool export zmt
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool export zmt1
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool import zmt
root@kkron-desktop:/# zpool import zmt1
```